# replace values between two dollar symbol

Tags: java

I need to replace a value between two dollar($) symbol.

below is the way i tried but i dont think it is an elegant way to do.

```
String queryNoAdditionalFilter= SELECT PRODUCTNAME,PRODUCTSKEY FROM PRODUCTS WHERE PRODUCTID=$productid$

    int start= queryNoAdditionalFilter.indexOf("$");
     int end= queryNoAdditionalFilter.lastIndexOf("$");
     String valueSubstitutedToFilter1 = queryNoAdditionalFilter.substring(start+1, end);
      String keyToReplace = "\\$"+valueSubstitutedToFilter1+"\\$";
     String valueSubstitutedToFilter2=queryNoAdditionalFilter.replaceAll(keyToReplace, "401250");


final outcome is :SELECT PRODUCTNAME,PRODUCTSKEY FROM PRODUCTS WHERE PRODUCTID=401250
```

which is the best way to implement this logic through java code?

Need your advise.

Comment: The best (and safest) way is to use a `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: use `StringUtils#substringBetween()`

Comment: @DuniyaHilaDalunga: Have you met [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)?

Comment: i dont want to depend with third party api. because stringutils with apache.

Comment: Why this aversion to 3rd party apis? You're ignoring a whole world of tried and tested solutions that will make your life so much easier

Comment: i wanted to use third party API. but due to our product restriction i m not able to take third party APIs as part of our packaging :(

Answer (score 3):

I think you should really use a [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

> Although PreparedStatement objects can be used for SQL statements with
>   no parameters, you probably use them most often for SQL statements
>   that take parameters. The advantage of using SQL statements that take
>   parameters is that you can use the same statement and supply it with
>   different values each time you execute it.

Here's how to use it (from the linked doc)

```
String updateString =
    "update " + dbName + ".COFFEES " +
    "set SALES = ? where COF_NAME = ?";
updateSales = con.prepareStatement(updateString);
updateSales.setInt(1, e.getValue().intValue());
updateSales.setString(2, e.getKey());
```

Comment: i was using prepared statement earlier but due to our design restriction i m not able to use because i m forming a query at runtime by reading details from database. i will be getting queries sometimes like SELECT COL1,COL2 FROM PRODUCTFEES WHERE PRODUCTID IN(select PRODUCTID FROM PRODUCTS WHERE PRODUCTID=$productid$ AND BANK_ID=$bankid$) AND BANK_ID=$bankid$;... so i cant fix the count of arguments at run time.

Comment: You can build the PreparedStatement from a string by appending clauses with '?' and then looping/invoking setInt(i)

Comment: I will try to use prepared statement and come back here soon